# Java Swing drawing app not drawing

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently writing a simple painting app in Java using the Swing libraries. Everything seems to be working fine -- mousePressed and mouseDragged both get called -- but the program does not paint anything on the drawing board. I'd be very happy if somebody could tell me why nothing ever gets drawn here.

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintGUI extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton red, green, blue, clear;
    Image img;
    Graphics2D gfx;
    JFrame drawFrame;
    JPanel drawPan;
    Container cont;
    MyListener ml;
    Action act;
    int x, y, prevX, prevY;

    public PaintGUI(){
        //Initialisering av panel, frame og content
        drawFrame = new JFrame("IFIPaint");
        drawPan = new JPanel();
        cont = drawFrame.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cont.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, drawPan);

        //Setter størrelser
        drawPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 60));
        drawPan.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 60));
        drawPan.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30, 60));

        //Ordner knappene
        red = new JButton("Rød");
        green = new JButton("Grønn");
        blue = new JButton("Blå");
        clear = new JButton("Slett alt");

        //Putter knappene på panelet
        drawPan.add(red);
        drawPan.add(green);
        drawPan.add(blue);
        drawPan.add(clear);

        //Legger på action listeners
        act = new Action();
        red.addActionListener(act);
        green.addActionListener(act);
        blue.addActionListener(act);
        clear.addActionListener(act);

        //Fullfører vindu og setter synlighet
        drawPan.setVisible(true);
        drawFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        drawFrame.setVisible(true);
        drawFrame.add(this);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.paintComponent(gfx);
        this.setVisible(true);

        drawFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        draw();
    }

    public void draw() {
        ml = new MyListener();
        this.addMouseListener(ml);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (img == null) {
            img = createImage(drawFrame.getWidth(),drawFrame.getHeight());

            gfx = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();

            gfx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            gfx.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
            gfx.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            gfx.setPaint(Color.RED);
            repaint();
        }

        gfx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }


    class Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == red){
                gfx.setPaint(Color.RED);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == green){
                gfx.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == blue) {
                gfx.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
                repaint();
            } else if (e.getSource() == clear) {
                gfx.clearRect(0, 0, drawFrame.getWidth(), drawFrame.getHeight());
                repaint();
            }
        }

    }

    class MyListener extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            prevX = e.getX();
            prevY = e.getY();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            gfx.drawLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);
            repaint();
            prevX = x;
            prevY = y;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `repaint` directly or indirectly within any paint method, doing so will cause a new paint event to be scheduled onto the event queue over and over again, quickly consuming your CPU.

You're not actually painting to the screen device, in order to do that, you need to paint to the supplied `Graphics` context

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    if (img == null) {
        img = createImage(drawFrame.getWidth(),drawFrame.getHeight());

        gfx = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();

        gfx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        gfx.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        gfx.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
        gfx.setPaint(Color.RED);
        // If you create it you should dispose of it...
        gfx.dispose();
    }

    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Because use `JComponent` is transparent by default, it is even more important that you call `super.paintComponent`, you'll end up with all sorts of nasty paint artifacts if you don't

The fact that are adding components onto the same drawing surface means that you could be obscuring what is getting painted.  Remember, not all components are transparent, `JPanel` is opaque by default.

A better solution would be to create a dedicated drawing panel which did nothing but painted what you want, they way you want.  This would then be added to another container along with the controls. You would then use setters to change how the painting occurred, such as using color for example

You seem to be trying to do double buffered approach.  It might be easier to separate the painting of the buffer from the painting of the component, this would allow you to modify the buffer any way you want to and then call repaint which would simply draw the image to the components `Graphics` context

Comment: I still can't get it working. I have made an edit now -- you can find it here: https://gist.github.com/henrik2706/64c3d92f469a7ca752a3

Comment: I have a main method as well.

Comment: Considering your creating a frame add building the UI within the PaintGUI class, which in of itself isn't a good idea, the PaintGUI component hasn't actually been added to anything that can actually display it...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in the paint component method make a call to super.

The reason that nothing is being drawn is that with this code you only update the image to be drawn if there is no image at present. I would change the `paintComponent` method to something like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    img = createImage(drawFrame.getWidth(),drawFrame.getHeight());
    gfx = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    gfx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    gfx.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    gfx.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
    gfx.setPaint(Color.RED);

    gfx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `drawPan` is obstructing you from seeing the image.

Remove its creation and addition to the content pane.