# Compatibility issues in swing drawing app OSX/Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing

I have a little drawing app that I've seen work on Windows machines, but I can't seem to make the lines drawn stick to the canvas when running this on a mac.

It starts up with a white background as specified, but as soon as I click&drag, the background disappears.

Small fragments of the lines are sometimes drawn to the canvas, after the white background disappears. While moving, the "brush" has a visible tail, but none of it sticks.

This is the sad result of a frantic spiral: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbbRU.png

I've looked at this: [Java Swing drawing app not drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910327/java-swing-drawing-app-not-drawing) which seems to somewhat answer this, but I'd really like to know about this specific code, as I've seen it work in on another machine.

Thanks much for any help!

Here is the code:

**DrawingApp.java**

```
public class DrawingApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window();
  }

}
```

**Window.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {

public Window() {
    setTitle("Tegneprogram");
    setSize(500, 400);
    Draw draw = new Draw();
    add(draw);
    setVisible(true);
  }


}
```

**Draw.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

Point start = null; 
Point end = null;

public Draw() {
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
  }

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
    start = end;
    end = new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    repaint();
  }

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
    end = null;
  }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (start != null && end != null)
        g.drawLine(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
  }

public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
  }


}
```

Comment: You should avoid setting things to `null`, it's a bad practice. You can create a `boolean drawing` instead. In your case these `null` objects may not have effect, but it's better getting used to avoid `NullPointerException`

Comment: Don't override `paint()`. Override `paintComponent()` instead, and make sure it first calls `super.paintComponent(g);`